# How can I place an Extjs app in SFDC visualforce page (built with sencha Cmd 6)?

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting, salesforce-sencha

I created an app using sencha Extjs, and built it with Sencha Cmd v6.0.1.76.

I created a object that handles calls to the @RemoteAction methods in the controller of the vfpage, and locally it works fine, but when I build it and upload it to the server, it gives errors like these:

-"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'desktop' of undefined" (on index.html)

-" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" (on classic.json)

The following is the content of the visualforce:

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.MassTransfer, 'classic/resources/MassTransfer-all.css')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.MassTransfer, 'classic/app.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.MassTransfer, 'classic.json')}"/>
<apex:iframe id="index" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.MassTransfer,'index.html')}" frameBorder="0" />
```

MassTransfer is a static resource that holds the production version of the app built with "sencha app build" command.

Comment: I spend some time trying to make it working as defined, via extjs loader, but met so much issues, so  I decided to make script, that join all the custom app together,and put it in static resource. Then i stop using extjs index html, and make as main page a VF page. Only then it started to work

Comment: Just to point that out, the app works fine locally.

Comment: In your case first thing that you need to do is check what is really returned to browser when it tires to get content.json and also ensure that if there are no classic/modern specified - something is being picked by default without any issues

Comment: @kurunve Can you elaborate in the method you used?

Comment: I think I would do it, but not now. Today or tomorrow